# Multidimensional scaling

Tags: r, multidimensional-scaling

I am running into some problems performing a multidimensional scaling image.
First of my dataset is quite large (330.000 fields: 33000 rows, 10 columns).
The output image needs to contain 10 dots, 1 for each column.
The fields in the dataset contain intensity values which first need to be converted to a distance matrix, however when doing so I run into a memory limit in R.

I was hoping you could help solve this problem or perhaps point me to a program that can handle these kind of data sizes.

Comment: What are you computing and how are you computing it? How much memory would it need? What version of R? 32 or 64 bit? What platform?

Comment: @Glen_b I am trying to analyze a dataset of logaritmic scores which are the result from a research institute, I am using windows 7 x64 but I can dual boot into ubuntu if needed. The amount of memory needed to run it in R is 32gb just to put it into a distance matrix before I can run a cmdscale.  That is why I ask for help here, I was hoping someone would know a program that could handle this amount of data with relatively little memory (10gb or so) which I know is a long shot.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is the method using too much memory, I do not have a suggestion, but if it is just your data taking up too much memory you could check out the [dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/databases.html) package, which enables you to create a local database with your data freeing memory.